# Samba not starting? Help Please

Tags: samba

jph@HEFFSVR2:~$ sudo apt-get install samba --install-recommends
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
samba is already the newest version (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.

---

Here is the results of
jph@HEFFSVR2:~$ journalctl -xe

---

```
Nov 29 15:57:44 HEFFSVR2 smartd[1761]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 115 to 114
Nov 29 15:57:44 HEFFSVR2 smartd[1761]: Device: /dev/sde [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 120 to 114
Nov 29 15:57:45 HEFFSVR2 smartd[1761]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 114 to 113
Nov 29 15:57:45 HEFFSVR2 smartd[1761]: Device: /dev/sdg [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 115 to 114
Nov 29 15:59:15 HEFFSVR2 systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit fwupd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Nov 29 15:59:28 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2207637]:      jph : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jph ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get install samba --install-recommends
Nov 29 15:59:28 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2207637]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 15:59:29 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2207637]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 16:00:43 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2401851]:      jph : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jph ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf.backup
Nov 29 16:00:43 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2401851]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 16:00:43 HEFFSVR2 smbd[2246740]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Nov 29 16:00:43 HEFFSVR2 gnome-shell[2624]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3c000f5
Nov 29 16:00:52 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2401851]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 16:01:00 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2449249]:      jph : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jph ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
Nov 29 16:01:00 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2449249]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 16:01:01 HEFFSVR2 gnome-shell[2624]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3c000f5
Nov 29 16:01:09 HEFFSVR2 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2473]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
Nov 29 16:01:11 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2449249]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 16:01:18 HEFFSVR2 systemd-resolved[1693]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 29 16:01:32 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2533037]:      jph : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jph ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
Nov 29 16:01:32 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2533037]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 16:01:32 HEFFSVR2 gnome-shell[2624]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x3c000f5
Nov 29 16:01:39 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2533037]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 16:01:50 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2581161]:      jph : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jph ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service smdb restart
Nov 29 16:01:50 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2581161]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 16:01:50 HEFFSVR2 sudo[2581161]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

---

jph@HEFFSVR2:~$ sudo service smdb restart
Failed to restart smdb.service: Unit smdb.service not found.

Here is my
jph@HEFFSVR2:~$ sudo gedit  /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   security = user
   usershare owner only = false 
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   interfaces = 192.168.1.73 eth0
   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   #map to guest = bad user
    force user = jph
   usershare allow guests = yes
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
[Users]
  path = /heffpool/udata
  browseable = yes
  read only = no
  force create mode = 0660
  force directory mode = 2770
  valid users = jph

 [homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S 
   
 [public]
  comment = public anonymous access
  path = /heffpool/udata
  browsable =yes
  create mask = 0660
  directory mask = 0771
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
```

---

Comment: Fix first: "*0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **58 not upgraded**.*" Try `sudo apt update`, followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`. If any errors, add the complete output to your question above.

Comment: `sudo service smdb restart Failed to restart smdb.service: Unit smdb.service not found.` looks like a simple spelling error (sm**db** should be sm**bd**)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reinstalling my server using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
```